# Editing vue production files in readable format

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I need to be able to edit vue build files in production. Its faster to modify production files on fly instead of finding right version of productioncode, changing it, building it and then deploying.

I tried prevent vue-cli and webpack to bundle it but that didnt work.

Problem is that vue build is not much readable to change. Is there any way to have build files in more readable format?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great idea. But if you need to, I would recommend [petite-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/petite-vue).

Or check out Vue's dokumentation on [using it without build tools](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#without-build-tools)